# How can I increase the margin for the caption of an in text image?

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

[image]

As shown in this image, the margin width between the writing and caption is frustrating me. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If \columnsep isn't big enough, you need to put the \caption into a minipage or \parbox to make it smaller.

Comment: What "margin"? Width between the caption and the text or the width between the image and the text? Or are you referring to the overhang into the margin? You should use some more descriptive text to explain what you mean by "frustrating," since that's subjective. What would a "fix" be?

Comment: Sorry @Werner, I should have clarified. I am referring to the width between the text and caption. It appears as though it is part of the text, which is frustrating. Having the entire image and caption moved a bit to the right so as to be further separated from the text would be a fix

Comment: [`wrapfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) provides an overhang component for this: `\begin{wrapfigure}[<lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>}` ... `\end{wrapfigure}`. Without specifying an `<overhang>`, it is assumed to be `0pt`. Try with `15pt`, say. Also, as John mentioned, `\columnsep` is the width between the regular text and the `wrapfigure` block, which you may want to adjust (increase; `\addtolength{\columnsep}{<len>}`, say).

Comment: Thanks for the help!